# MySQL Information Schema is different from DESC Result

Tags: mysql, database, information-schema

I've a table with a column that was created with type "date". Later the type was changed to "datetime".

desc  shows column type as datetime, but if I find the column type from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS then the datatype is shown as "date". Here is the query

```
    SELECT column_name, data_type, column_type
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
     WHERE table_name = '<My Table Name>'
    AND column_name = '<Column Name>'
```

This shows data_type and column_type as "date"

My question is why does "desc " shows different datatype than the one displayed by the query.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eqzR8Z9R).

Comment: @wchiquito thanks a lot for reply. The problem I see is only for one particular column. Other datetime columns are show "datetime" when I DESCRIBE  the table or when I execute  query on INFORMATION_SCHEMA. My SQL Version is 5.7.38

Comment: Can you post your table structure and some test data? In version 5.7.39 I am unable to reproduce the problem in a very simple example, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zQ69sFFv). See [13.1.18.6 Silent Column Specification Changes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/silent-column-changes.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot @wchiquito for your support. Please see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y19f4yx8). I've exported a single column of interest and relevant data. In dbfiddle I've also added the query used to find "date" type column. Results are included.